# Получать значения checkbox

Tags: php, html, input, checkbox

Как получать значения `checkbox`, которые выбрал пользователь? `value` не вариант, ибо это показатель правильности/неправильности ответа на вопрос. `name` тоже одинаков.

```html
    <p>1. Вопрос 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="0"><i>1</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"><i>2</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="0"><i>3</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="0"><i>4</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"><i>5</i>
  </p>
  <p>2. Вопрос 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="1"><i>1</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="0"><i>2</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="1"><i>3</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="0"><i>4</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="0"><i>5</i>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Для name у всех checkbox`ов лучше использовать массив.
2. Не вариант выкладывать ответы в HTML-форму, которую сможет просмотреть пользователь! Ответы нужно хранить в PHP-скрипте, например, в массиве.

   ```
    <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="1"><i>1</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="2"><i>2</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="3"><i>3</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="4"><i>4</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="5"><i>5</i>   

    <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="1"><i>1</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="2"><i>2</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="3"><i>3</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="4"><i>4</i><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q2[]" value="5"><i>5</i>
   ```

Наброски кода на PHP

```
<?php
$q[1]['true_answers'] = [2, 5]; // Правильные ответы на вопрос №1

// Обработка ответов на вопрос №1
if (is_array($_POST['q1'])) {
    $q1_request = $_POST['q1'];
    foreach ($q1_request AS $answer) {
        echo $answer."\n";
    }
}
```